WPF/C# - dropbox style - cannot click on ToggleButton background
I gathered code here and there to make a custom combo box
yet I can only click on the arrow to select an item
I want to be able to click on the whole ToggleButton, not just the arrow
for some reason nothing happens when I click in the red zone

even clicking on the borders seem to work
here is the style:
`
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ComponentTextColor}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border CornerRadius="3,0,0,3"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="{DynamicResource ComponentBgColor}"
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ComponentBorderColor}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border 
                    Background="{DynamicResource BgComponentColor}" 
                    x:Name="border" 
                    CornerRadius="0,3,3,0" 
                    BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ComponentBorderColor}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ComponentTextColor}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ComponentTextColor}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ComponentTextColor}" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid Height="30">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Padding="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}"/>
                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" ClickMode="Press" Focusable="False" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxButtonStyle}" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Path Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" Fill="{DynamicResource ComponentBorderColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="Slide" >
                        <Grid x:Name="DropDown" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{DynamicResource ComponentBgColor}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ComponentBorderColor}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                                <StackPanel KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

`
The Combo box is a simple one, no fancy trick here:
           ` <ComboBox Name="scalesList"  Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="ScaleWheelScaleChanged" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>`

I tried triggers but it does not seem to do anything
please help me I am out of ideas, I tried so many things, nothing works
thanks for your help

What is BgComponentColor? Try to replace it with Transparent.

wow, actually I renamed it to ComponentBgColor, changing it to the right name fixed the issue, how can it be ?

Null value to Background makes the background not hit test visible and prevents it from caputring mouse inputs.

ComponentBgColor was the correct color resource name
and using an incorrect name,for some reason, did cause the issue

